# Cannot save property as decimal

Tags: c#, entity-framework, razor, html-helper

In my model I use property.

```
[Display(Name = "Pensja")]
public decimal? Salary { get; set; }
```

In Edit Razor View I want to change value from 4000,00 to 4000,50.
In View it looks like this.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Salary, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Salary, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Salary, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I get the message that Salary must be a number. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you use Html.BeginForm ?  How do you send data on controller ? Please update Question with detail.

Comment: I use Html.BeginForm

Comment: this message is Client Validation error message   ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your error msg is on the client side (jscipt) and think your language is Polish, so you may need to configure few things related to your locale.

Take a look to this url http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg674880(VS.98).aspx and https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/jquery-globalization-plugin-from-microsoft

OR disable your clientside validation

```
  @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); }
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Salary, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(true); }
```

Comment: Yes, my language is Polish.

Comment: The other option is to disable the client validation or add a customized one

Comment: Shoud I remove ValidationMessageFor and something else?

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to disable the clientside validation

Answer (score 0):

I check your question and this message is `Client validation` message and it's probably true.

You must be use **correct** `valdiation` script because the currency separator differs from countries

please check this article [validation-polish](https://github.com/DivanteLtd/jquery-validation-polish)
and look at this https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

Also I have found another solution.
In View.

```
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Salary, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="text" name="UserSalary" id="UserSalary" value="@Model.Salary"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

In controller.

```
decimal salary;
                Decimal.TryParse(Request.Form["UserSalary"].ToString(), NumberStyles.Any, new CultureInfo("pl-PL"), out salary);
                user.Salary = salary;
```